# Canvas quiz imported through exams2canvas is missing solution materials/answer feedback

Tags: r, canvas, r-exams

I exported the quiz generated by sample code of exams2canvas:

```
library("exams")
options(device.ask.default = FALSE)
set.seed(0)
## define an exams (= list of exercises)
myexam <- c(
  "boxplots",
  "tstat",
  "ttest",
  "regression",
  "relfreq"
)

## output directory
dir.create(mydir <- tempfile())

## generate .zip with OpenOLAT test in temporary directory
exams2canvas(myexam, n = 3, dir = mydir)
dir(mydir)
```

I was able to import the zip file into Canvas as a quiz. However, when I check the quiz, the comment for each answer appears to be missing. I checked the xml file generated by `exams2canvas()` and the file does contain solutions and explanations for each question in the `<solutionmaterial>` block. For some reason they are not imported to Canvas.

Any pointers to help fix this issue will be very much appreciated!

[image: Screenshot 1 of empty comments here]

[image: Screenshot 2 of empty comments here]

Edit: Included screenshot of empty comments.

Comment: I cannot replicate this. I created the .zip file after `set.seed(0)` to be exactly reproducible. Then I imported it as "QTI .zip file" which worked for me correctly in two separate Canvas installations.

Comment: Did you double check whether your problem persists? If so, maybe you can provide further details that might help us to replicate the issue.

Comment: @AchimZeileis Thank you for getting back to me. I did set.seed(0). But the comment boxes are still empty. I have included a screenshot in my edited answer above.

Comment: @AchimZeileis Another thing that started to happen today is that I am unable to import the zip file to Canvas if myexam includes "regression". I had to comment out that question for the rest to import. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Thanks for checking and for posting the screenshots. These helped in understanding your problem but unfortunately I still can't solve it. I tried one more time to import the `canvasquiz.zip` file as "QTI .zip" on the Canvas community server (<https://canvas.instructure.com/>). There, everything went smoothl and the feedback worke.

Comment: Thanks. Would it be possible to share your canvasquiz.zip file so I could isolate the issue a bit further, @AchimZeileis

Comment: I have posted the `canvasquiz.zip` file in a companion discussion in our R-Forge forum: https://R-Forge.R-project.org/forum/forum.php?thread_id=34319&forum_id=4377&group_id=1337 You should be able to view the post and download the file without registration on R-Forge. If you want to post a follow-up comment there, you need to register, though (but it's free). If we find a solution, we can still follow up here...but SO is not intended for long exchanges back and forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the issue was because I was using an older version of r-exams (exams_2.3-6). Once I updated the package to the development version (currently exams_2.4-0) using

```
install.packages("exams", repos="https://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

as suggested by @AchimZeileis in [this thread](https://r-forge.r-project.org/forum/forum.php?thread_id=34319&forum_id=4377&group_id=1337), then the question-level feedback displays correctly in Canvas.

Big shout-out to Achim and the entire r-exams team for developing a tremendously useful package and for the helpful and detailed responses.

Answer (score 2):

Prompted by a comment in an accompanying [thread in the R/exams forum on R-Forge](https://R-Forge.R-project.org/forum/forum.php?thread_id=34319&forum_id=4377&group_id=1337), I think I may have understood what the source of the misunderstanding is here.

For single- and multiple-choice questions in R/exams it is possible (but not necessary) to include feedback for each choice element. However, in `exams2canvas()` this is not show as element-wise feedback but as general feedback below the entire item. This has the advantage that all feedback is in one place, can easily be combined with other general feedback, and also the feedback to correct answers is included. Usually, this works well even if there is just a list of element-wise feedback. See the screenshot below for an example.

We have discussed potentially supporting the same feedback elements in different ways in Canvas. However, so far this is the only option. Further variations may be added in the future but are not planned at the moment.

[image: screenshot of the R/exams 'boxplots' exercise in Canvas]